# How do I handle a c++ exception from an unmanaged DLL as a custom C# exception using Swig?

Tags: c#, c++, swig, unmanaged

Basically, I am using some unmanaged c++ code to handle some of the openGL components of my project. The goal is to be able to throw meaningful custom exceptions accordingly when something happens in OpenGL. From my understanding SWIG will naturally catch exceptions as an SEH exception, but I would like to know where in the code the exception is thrown from by using custom exceptions. I am currently using SWIG. I have read the documentation on the SWIG site:
http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html (Section 18.4.4)

So I put the following code in the interface file:

```
%insert(runtime) %{
  typedef void (SWIGSTDCALL* CSharpExceptionCallback_t)(const char *);
  CSharpExceptionCallback_t customExceptionCallback = NULL;

  extern "C" SWIGEXPORT
  void SWIGSTDCALL CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(CSharpExceptionCallback_t customCallback) {
    customExceptionCallback = customCallback;
  }

  static void SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom(const char *msg) {
    customExceptionCallback(msg);
  }
%}

%pragma(csharp) imclasscode=%{
class CustomExceptionHelper {

    class CustomApplicationException : System.ApplicationException
    {
        public CustomApplicationException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }
    }

    public delegate void CustomExceptionDelegate(string message);
    static CustomExceptionDelegate customDelegate =
                                   new CustomExceptionDelegate(SetPendingCustomException);

    [DllImport("$dllimport", EntryPoint="CustomExceptionRegisterCallback")]
    public static extern
           void CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(CustomExceptionDelegate customCallback);

    static void SetPendingCustomException(string message) {
      SWIGPendingException.Set(new CustomApplicationException(message));
    }

    static CustomExceptionHelper() {
      CustomExceptionRegisterCallback(customDelegate);
    }
  }
  static CustomExceptionHelper exceptionHelper = new CustomExceptionHelper();
%}

%typemap(throws, canthrow=1) std::out_of_range {
  SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionCustom($1.what());
  return $null;
}
```

Them I have my necessary methods

```
void foo() throw (std::out_of_range)
{
     throw std::out_of_range("Custom Exception");
}
```

However this is still interpreted as an SEH exception and all the information I can get is that an external component threw an exception. Any advice or something I'm missing?